# How do I combine two probabilities?

Tags: probability

I need to find the probability of at least 4 correct numbers being drawn in a lottery with a draw of 43. I can find the probability of 5 and the probability of 6, but I don't know how to combine the two probabilities to find the probability of either 5 or 6 being drawn.

Comment: So the Lottery Corporation chooses $6$ distinct numbers from $43$, you choose $6$, and you want probability either $5$ or $6$ of your numbers match the Corp. numbers? Add the prob. of exactly $5$ right and the probability of $6$ right.

Answer (score 1):

When events are mutually exclusive, meaning only one can happen, the probability that either one happens is the sum of the probabilities of each.  In your case, you cannot get both exactly $6$ right and exactly $5$ right, so you can add them to get the probability that you get either $5$ or $6$.  But if you want the probability of at least $4$, you have to add in the chance of exactly $4$ as well.

Answer (score 1):

Just add them up.

Assume event A is that 4 correct numbers are drawn, event B is that 5 correct numbers are drawn, and event C is that 6 correct numbers are drawn.

$$Pr(\mbox{at least 4 numbers are drawn})=Pr(A+B+C)$$

We know that event A, B, and C are disjoint.

So
$$Pr(A+B+C)=Pr(A)+Pr(B)+Pr(C)$$